# UITableView does not return to the right place after a bounce when using custom section height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I need to set custom section height for my table view, and I'm trying to do it in pretty straightforward way by calling some delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 39.0;
}
```

I do get desired result - a taller section but I'v noticed one problem. When I tap the table (start dragging), move my finger up to top, and release the table, then the table bounces back but does not return to the correct initial place. If What I mean is the section header overlaps the first row. Here is the screen:

[image]

Any ideas why this happens or what workarounds exist?

UPDATE: I also tried increasing section height property of the tableView in IB. This increases the height but the same problem exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're dragging the table up so that the last row of the table, plus empty space below it, is showing, like this:

[image: table view dragged up]

When you let go, it slides the table back down so that bottom edge of the last table row is flush against the bottom edge of the view.

This is the expected behavior for a table view.  You're seeing the top row slip partly underneath your section header because the view height, minus the section header height, isn't an integer multiple of the row height.  If you don't like this, you need to make sure the view height minus the section header height *is* an integer multiple of the row height.

Comment: Your are absolutely right. Yesterday I didn't notice that because there was only 8 rows in the table. With default section header the whole table exactly fits full screen on the iPhone. After increasing section height, the whole table view expanded and no longer was fitting in the screen. Thanks for the notice & GL ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to set the section height without using the delegate:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 39.0;
```

If this does not help, you will have to fiddle with the `UIScrollView Delegate`.

Also, from your screen shot I see that you might be interested in the property `tableHeaderView`, which is a header above the table that will scroll off-screen when the table view is scrolled.

Comment: Thanks but was unable to get at least section height increased :(   Tried setting "self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 39.0;" in viewDidLoad && viewWillAppear, but the section height is not increasing at all. Also tried increasing the frame height of tableHeaderView to 39.0 but the height was also not increasing at all.